# ubuntu 12.10 Lenovo b570e, WiFi connected but not working

Tags: networking, 12.10, dns

I'm running ubuntu 12.10 liveUSB on a lenovo b570e. It has an atheros wifi card that connects with my home network but I can't browse AT ALL.

My network is `multiple clients --> router --> isp modem --> Internet`

I can ping my router (192.168.0.1) but not my isp's modem(192.168.15.1). I have 3 other computers connected to the same router that are working fine (infact i'm posting from one)

```
ping -c 3 google.com
unknown host google.com
ping -c 3 8.8.8.8 shows 100% packet loss
```

I think its some networking issue. I tried directly connecting it to the router via ethernet cable but same issue. It gets an ip, shows LAN connected but can't browse. If I connect it directly to the isp modem via ethernet cable it starts working fine.

Connection Information shows:

```
Interface: 802.11 wifi (wlan0)
driver: ath9k
security: wpa/wpa2
speed: 150mb/s

ip: 192.168.0.106
broadcast: 192.168.0.255
subnet:255.255.255.0
default route: 192.168.0.1
primary dns: 192.168.15.1
```

i have restarted the router and modem many times. Rebooted the LiveUSB many times.

Comment: Ccan you ping 192.168.0.106 from other machine?

Comment: yes i can ping ...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/19593-ubuntu-1204-wifi-not-working-at-laptop-or-notebook-unblock-it

**Check if the wifi card is blocked** (Terminal)

`rfkill list wlan`     (**for wifi**)

OR

`rfkill list all`             (**for wifi and bluetooth**)

**UNBLOCK**:

`rfkill unblock wlan`     (for **wifi**)

**OR**

`rfkill unblock all`             (for **wifi** and **bluetooth**)

Restart the network:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: My wifi is not blocked. It's connecting to the router. The problem seems to be resolved without any intervention on my part. I rebooted it again and it suddenly started working.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Have been using ubuntu "forever" and many other linuxen before.
I updgraded from 12.04 to 12.10  on the weekend and "lost internet".
Yes, my network manager sees the wireless access point (and others, those in my neighbourhood) all right,
ifconfig looks "ok" : shows  wlan0
with
inet addr:192.168.1.104  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mas:255.255.255.0
inet6 .....
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST   MTU:1500 Metric:1

etc.
Also, all my other computers continue to work fine with WLAN router.
(Yes, using an ethernet cable to the router is the same)...

Interestingly, at work, it connects fine to the ethernet (ie cable).  There the authentication is only via  HWaddr  (where my notebook's is registered), so possibly not via DHCP.

This is a major PITA....  never seen...
and yes, I'd be grateful for hints   (yes, this e-mail is written from another computer w/o problem...
also my old notebook with ubuntu 10.04.1  works fines  (though too slow...).
Martin

Comment: When you say "lost internet", do you mean DNS resolution error? While googling, one of the suggested answers was to change DNS servers. You can try it on the machine giving error by adding Google or opendns servers via Network Manager.

Comment: Yes, indeed it was *only* DNS...  and the hint I got somewhere to try   ping 8.8.8.8   was really a good one as indeed it proved the "DNS-only" problem.    Now the solution: incredibly simple and "good old school":  My  /etc/resolv.conf  file contained "complete nonsense" *and* this probably came about, because I use a VPN  (cisco anyconnect client) *during* my ubuntu upgrade..  So that file ended up containing *only* the remote nameserver (from my university) which was only working when the VPN was active.   Solution:  nameserver 192.186.1.1  in that file, and nameserver 8.8.8.8 just in case.